# MemoryCacheEntryOptions cache is not cleared after AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow is expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have sample webapp deployed to Azure.  The app cached a variable using MemoryCacheEntryOptions to store a value (from database) which expire in 5 minutes.

However after 5 minutes via Chrome debugging tool, I still can query the cache, the cache value expected to be empty or whatever the new value which currently stored updated in the database.

I even tried to clear cache in the web browser, but cache seem still retain the previous value.

However when I restart the web site, and open the web app again the cache value is no longer exist.

Would any setting in Azure might affect the cache expiry?

```
private readonly MemoryCacheEntryOptions _cacheEntryOptions;
protected CacheService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _ memoryCache = memoryCache;
 _cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
  { 
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)
  };
}
```

Comment: You make a `MemoryCacheEntryOptions` and save it into a field, but never use it. The settings are not attached to your memorycache

Comment: Your code seems a bit messy. You should create an instance of `MemoryCacheEntryOptions` only when you call `IMemoryCache.Set` method. The options must be instantiated and used only when you wan to save something in your cache. Also, the web browser cache is not related to your server side in-memory cache. There is no relation between server side app caching capabilities and web browser HTTP cache. How can you verify the behavior of your server side code by using Google Chrome dev tools ?

Answer (score -1):

Debugging the behavior of a web application is notoriously hard, as all you got to control it is the Browser - and you never get exclusive access.

Even if you did not refresh the page, any number of things might have queried the server. The culprits start around "any search engines webcrawler" and end around "somewhat aggressive security tools" (because some viruses might use web servers). You could try a way shorter timeout. But ideally you want to have both the Server and the client you access it with run in separate virtual machines, which are only connected via the Hypervisor. That way you can be certain nobody is interfering.